Design a nondeterministic Turing machine that the tape head move to the right of the input in exponential time
More specificly, I want a nondeterministic Turing machine(NTM) $N$ such that for every input $w$ of length $n$, the tape head is initially on the first letter. The transition allows the head to move right, move left, or stay in current location. The tape head cannot move left when it is on the first letter. I want N, for every $2^{n-1}\leq i\leq 2^n-1$, has a path that the tape head moves to the n-th letter right after $i$ steps. How can I do it?
It remind me of random walk. However, I hope to make every path have time complexity of $exp(n)$.

Two questions: 1. Why non-deterministic? It feels that non-determinism doesn't help here. 2. Do you want the exact bound $2^{n-1} \leq i \leq 2^n - 1$? Or would you be satisfied with $\Theta(2^n)$? If the latter, then you can just implement a binary counter on the tape, and the first time the head touches cell $n$ will be at time step $\Theta(2^n)$.
